# What kind of completeness is the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

As opposed to the algebraic completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, which yields the algebraic numbers, we can say that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete in the sense that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ bounded by above has a supremum.

So, it isn't *algebraically* complete, but is it topologically or metrically complete? What would be the right word to describe its completeness?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a complete metric space. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reals are complete as a metric space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Completeness) and as an ordered set in the sense of Dedekind (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_completion), and also categorically as the unique complete Archimedean ordered field.

Comment: It's also topologically complete (A Tychonov space that is a $G_\delta$ in its Cech-Stone compactification) as it is even locally compact.

Comment: See also [Propositions equivalent to the completeness of the real numbers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62340/propositions-equivalent-to-the-completeness-of-the-real-numbers).

Comment: See also [Real Analysis in Reverse](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.4483).